# Why does this result in a "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range" exception?

Tags: postgresql, ignition

I'm trying to run a function in a PostgreSQL 11 server from Ignition (8.0.16) as a named-query and getting a column index error. Everywhere that has discussed this error with regards to Postgres shows it is an issue of the parameters provided and expected not matching in number.

It always shows as one more than the number provided as being out of range. Even when changed to use a different number of parameters.

I count 13 everywhere: Ignition parameters, test parameters, the function call in Ignition, the function definition, the table. Here is the function call from Ignition:

```
SELECT insert_run_data(
:speed_in,
:avg_speed_in,
:coater_num_in,
:coater_op_in,
:finisher_in,
:helper1_in,
:helper2_in,
:coater_down_in,
:current_downtime_reason_in,
:hanging_downtime_reason_in,
:tabcode_in,
:start_time_in,
:end_time_in
);
```

In the same named-query window, if I comment out the function call and try to write directly using the same parameters, it writes without issue:

```
insert into 
nh_coater_tabcode_operator_data(
speed, avg_speed, coater_num, coater_op, finisher, helper1,
helper2, coater_down, current_downtime_reason,
hanging_downtime_reason, tabcode, start_time, end_time
)
  
values(:speed_in, :avg_speed_in, :coater_num_in, :coater_op_in,
:finisher_in, :helper1_in, :helper2_in, :coater_down_in,
:current_downtime_reason_in, :hanging_downtime_reason_in, :tabcode_in,
:start_time_in, :end_time_in
);
```

The function also runs fine from within PGAdmin.

Here are gists showing the SQL used to create the table and function, the stack trace from Ignition, and an image showing the named-query authoring window parameters matching:

[create function gist](https://gist.github.com/HelloMorrisMoss/aad54d5f04bc19728d22d7b9919db165)

[create table gist](https://gist.github.com/HelloMorrisMoss/4c4cab0901f142cfff236cad1442ce24)

[stack trace of error gist](https://gist.github.com/HelloMorrisMoss/83aa9163e149cfd3afcb93240e9712bf)

[parameters in Ignition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQHP0.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Ignition Designer seems to cache the function. So, if it is changed, you will need to save and reopen the project: open another then switch back or close and open a new designer window.